# build failing on a Jenkins on a given branch due to path export

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, git, jenkins

I have a chunk of files related to a new feature that will be deployed using Jenkins.
I was able to deploy other branches, but I have been facing issues with a given branch.
[image: Error log]
I suspect the issue might have to do with the usage root scope.
and below is the piece of code related to the issue

```
fetchLeaseForm().then(function
() {

// setWebViewerForCustomTemplate($scope.selected.leaseForm.lease_form_template.document_path)

$rootScope.template_url
= $scope.selected.leaseForm.lease_form_template?.document_path
console.log($scope.selected.leaseForm.lease_form_template?.document_path,
'@@fetchleaseformthen')
$rootScope.customLeaseFormDropdown()
})
```

I have tried aking for the latest pull from the master so that cant is a possible issue.
And I was able to push it on git without any issues.

Any insight on  this issue would be helpful

Comment: It looks like the error is due to the question mark. For debugging, try changing `$scope.selected.leaseForm.lease_form_template?.document_path` to `$scope.selected.leaseForm.lease_form_template != null ? $scope.selected.leaseForm.lease_form_template.document_path : null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```js
fetchLeaseForm().then(function
() {

// setWebViewerForCustomTemplate($scope.selected.leaseForm.lease_form_template.document_path)

$rootScope.template_url
= $scope?.selected?.leaseForm?.lease_form_template?.document_path

  if($rootScope?.template_url) {
   console.log($scope.selected.leaseForm.lease_form_template?.document_path,
    '@@fetchleaseformthen')
  }
})
```